# Business Data Connectivity Service

Tags: sharepoint

I am reading this article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683108.aspx

On step 6b it says to:
In the Database area, leave the prepopulated values for Database Server, Database Name, and Database authentication, which is Windows authentication (recommended) unless you have specific design needs to change them.

However my question on that is the prepopulated values for the database server is Sharepoint. why would I want that as a default if I am trying to set up an external database for external content types?

I want to make sure my understanding is correct before I make a change at this high level of SharePoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document you are referring to is about setting up BDC service. The database mentioned in step 6 is not the database containing the external data but internal database of BDC service that will hold the configuration data of the service.

Setting up new connection for particular data source is another step (following the BDC service setup). You can definitely connect to remote servers.

Comment: the site for the setup makes it seem I am trying to make my external database sharepoint itself rather than Sharepoint database being an proxy